# Undefined variable: productChunk

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone tell me what is wrong here because I believe I have followed the tutorial perfectly however it is throwing this error.

I need to fix it.

The error is:

> Undefined variable: productChunk

code is

```html
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
 Laravel Shopping Cart
@endsection

@section('content')
  @foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productchunk)
    <div class="row">
      @foreach($productChunk as $product)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://prodimage.images-bn.com/pimages/9781338099133_p0_v5_s1200x630.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Product Title</h3>
          <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <div class="clearfix">
          <div class="pull-left price">£12</div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: I guess it should be `@foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productChunk)` and not `as $productchunk)`

Comment: Your completely right! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand the concept first, you can pass an array in view() method lik:

controller:

```
return view('dirname.viewname', array('index' => $value));
```

now $index is available on viewname.blade.php. If $value contains an array that you can iterate it using foreach. Otherwise you can use it like a variable.

In your case the problem is on following line:

```
@foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productchunk)
```

here you have to pass the proper variable name which is present in view() method.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 @foreach($productchunk as $product)
```